# express cors request.body formData show undefined

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, form-data

I'm imitating cors request to express.
The status is ok, and request and response are succesfull. Network shows payload filled with form data. Hovewer in nodejs terminal  logs in console `undefined`.

Sending the form fieds with follow code:

```
<form id="formElt">
    <input type="text" name="FirstInput" id="" value="FirstInputValue"/>
    <input type="text" name="SecondInput" id="" value="SecondInputValue"/>
</form>
<button class="postBtn">POST</button>
<script>
postBtn.onclick = async () => {          
    let formElt = this.querySelector('#formElt');
    let fd = new FormData(formElt);
    fd.append('testInput', 'TestInputValue');
    await fetch('http://localhost:8080/add', {
        method: 'post',
        body: fd                
    })
    .then(res => {
         return res.text();                  
    })
    .then(data=>{
         p.innerText = data;
    })
}
</script>
```

On the nodejs side there is:

```
const Router = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const router = Router();
router.use(cors())
const postOptions = {
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
}
router.post('/add', cors(postOptions), (req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('hello from node! Data received!');
})
```

[image]

Comment: Does this problem only happen when your send fd in your body? Did you try it with a String?

Comment: I'am not clear what's the process. Even, after `fd.append('testInput', 'TestInputValue')` call `console.log(fd)` the console logs an empty `FormData {}`. But, why payload fills with expected content?

Comment: Try passing a String in the body.
F.e. body: 'foo'

See if the response is undefined there.

Comment: Exactly the same.Payload shows: Request Payload 'foo', nodejs logs `undefined`

Comment: Try defining your String in a variable before. In your Body use:

JSON.stringify(VARNAME)

Let me know if that worked

Comment: Oh and on the server parse it so you get your Object back.

With JSON.parse(req.body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing code for `form-data` decoding in `express`.

```
// for form-data
const multer = require('multer');
const forms = multer();
router.use(forms.array());
```

Full code
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, intial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="is=edge" />
    <title>Form data</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="formElt">
      <input type="text" name="FirstInput" id="" value="FirstInputValue" />
      <input type="text" name="SecondInput" id="" value="SecondInputValue" />
    </form>
    <button id="postBtn">POST</button>
    <script>
      postBtn.onclick = async () => {
        let formElt = document.getElementById("formElt");
        let fd = new FormData(formElt);
        fd.append("testInput", "TestInputValue");
        await fetch("http://localhost:8080/add", {
          method: "post",
          body: fd,
        })
          .then((res) => {
            return res.text();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            p.innerText = data;
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const Router = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const router = Router();
router.use(cors())

// for form-data
const multer = require('multer');
const forms = multer();
router.use(forms.array()); 

// for x-www-form-urlencoded
router.use(Router.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// for raw JSON
router.use(Router.json()); 

const postOptions = {
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
}

router.post('/add', cors(postOptions), (req, res)=> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
    res.send('hello from node! Data received!');
})

router.listen(8080, () => { console.log("Listening on :8080") })
```

launching server

```
node server.js
```

Launch index.html from VS code by Go-Live extension.
[image]

received data at `server.js`

[image]

If using just `JSON.stringify(req.body)`, will shows this output

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

[image]

POST three different Body data types.
It matched `server.js` decoding and `result` at server and Postman POST call.

[image]

Comment: Well done, and hope is nice when  have an explanation about `JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4)` later parameters.
From my side, I already have a log from nodejs with body by inserting `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'S},` in fetch,  just after `method: 'post,`. And `allowHeaders : 'Content-Type'` in cors `postOptions` constant. Such trying to get without multer. Only still have an answer unconvinient, like `'------WebKitFormBoundaryCYWxIVHYmze4G7gO\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"FirstInput"\r\n' + '\r\n' +'FirstInputValue\r\n' ...`
Well, continue...

Comment: The JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4), shows JSON string with 4 space indent in terminal, the detail information  in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). I don't understand your header's explaining.

Comment: I added the output if use `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));`

Comment: Fetch now looks like this:
`await fetch('http://localhost:8081/add', {method: 'post',headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },body: fd })`
and so on. 
cors postOptions looks:
`const postOptions = {origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500', allowHeaders: 'Content-Type'}
`
In this way I do not require to install multer, but `console.log(req.body)` looks not empty but with payload

Comment: I update my answer, the relationships between a data header and data result and client by Postman.

Comment: Multer is an awesome tool

Comment: Don't forget vote me.